# Does vscode-dev-containers work with non-Docker containers like LXC?

Tags: visual-studio-code, lxc, vscode-remote

In the website of visualstudio at the following link:

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/remote-overview

the website says that **VS Code Remote Development** can connect in 3 ways:

- Remote SSH
- Remote - Containers
- Remote - WSL

In the link about [Containers](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/containers) the page says:

> Linux: Docker CE/EE 18.06+ and Docker Compose 1.21+. (The Ubuntu snap package is not supported.)

But also says:

> Other glibc based Linux containers may work if they have needed Linux prerequisites.

So it is unclear if the extension works with non-Docker containers.

Is it possible to use this extension to develop software inside LXC containers(locally or remotely)?

Answer (score 0):

LXC and LXD are *system containers*, therefore you can definitely use the *Remote SSH* method.

The Containers method has been designed for Docker. It might be possible to get it to work with LXD with an appropriate `devcontainer.json`, but you would need to figure this one out. I could not find an existing guide for this.

Answer (score 0):

One could do with Ansible and LXD , infact it would be nicer.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I was able to by taking the following steps (note: I am referring specifically to Incus containers, not LXD):

1. When creating your Incus container, pay particular attention to using the right parameters. As an example, I created a container using this

   ```
   incus launch images:ubuntu/22.04 python-microservice --profile default --profile bridgeprofile -c security.privileged=true -c security.nesting=true -c limits.memory=4096MB -c limits.cpu=2 -c boot.autostart=true
   ```
2. Edit your `.ssh/config` file, and add a new configuration section for your Incus instance.  As an example:

   ```
   Host "name of your instance"
     Hostname "IP address of your instance"
     User "root or whatever user you want to use"
   ```
3. In Visual Studio Code, search for marketplace extensions related to remote ssh
4. In the Command Palette, search for Remote-SSH Connect to Host
5. You should be able to select the Incus instance you created from step 2
6. In Visual Studio Code, open a terminal.  You should now be logged into your instance. Make sure you setup your ssh public key on the instance.

From this point, you should be able to install docker and continue your work.